# Doubling the cube, field extensions and minimal polynoms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, geometric-construction

I know the proof of the "[Doubling the cube problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube)". What is used there is the fact that if a number $a$ is constructible then $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ is a power of $2$.

I found in a German textbook the remark that the inversion is not correct:
If $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ is a power of $2$, then $a$ is not necessarily constructible.

Do you know an example for an $a$ where $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ is a power of $2$ and which is not constructible – or a textbook with an example?

Comment: I think it is "constructible", not "constructable".

Comment: A number $a\in\mathbb{C}$ is constructible if and only if the degree of the splitting field of its minimal polynomial (which might be larger than $\mathbb{Q}(a)$) over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a power of $2$. You can find the proof here: http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN8.pdf

Comment: It follows for example that any root of $x^4-4x+2$ is not constructible. The Galois group of this polynomial is $S_4$, so its order is not a power of $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cox's *Galois Theory*, Example 10.1.13 (p.263) gives the example $f(x)=x^4-4x^2+x+1$. It is irreducible, so if $f(a)=0$ then $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]=4$. However, the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree 24.

Cox also shows that $a$ is constructible if and only if the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree a power of 2, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$. (Theorem 10.1.12, p.262). Therefore the above $a$ is not constructible.

Answer (score 1):

The set of constructible numbers is the smallest extension of $\Bbb Q$ where each positive number has a square root. (That's essentially what straightedge and compass constructions are able to do: field operations and square roots.) Every constructible number can be described by using rational numbers, field operations and square roots.

I can't construct a concrete example of the following off the top of my head. But it is relatively well-known that there are irreducible degree 8 polynomials that aren't solvable through radicals. A root of such a polynomial won't be expressible with only the rational numbers, field operations and square roots. Thus it won't be constructible. Yet the field extension you get from adjoining such a root to $\Bbb Q$ has degree $8$.

Answer (score 1):

The [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) solving the quartic involve taking cube roots in general. Some [auxiliary cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic) equation is needed in the resolution of a quartic in general.